# pgfplots: minor ticks starting at 1.5, not 0.5

Tags: pgfplots

The following code is used to produce the plot below.

```
\pgfplotsset{
    axis equal image,
    xtick={1,2,3,4},
    ytick={1},
    minor y tick num={1},
    minor x tick num={1},
    xmin=-0.3, 
    xmax=4.2, 
    ymin=-0.3, 
    ymax=2.2,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel=$t$,
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=1pt}
}   

(...)     

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [ylabel=$s_6(t)$]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Now I wonder why there is no 0.5 tick, neither at the X, nor the Y axis. I know that I can manually add them, but then there will be captions as well (which I don't like). Can anyone help me out to explain what wrong assumptions I made or which pitfall I ran into?

Comment: Instead of providing the complete tick list explicitly, you can also use `xtick={0,...,4}`, which will fill in the numbers using a step of `1`. If you want a different step size, you can specify the first two numbers in the series, e.g. `xtick={0,5,...,50}` would give you the numbers `0, 5, 10, 15` etc.

Comment: @Jake, thank you for the hint -- indeed this makes the code more pretty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add zero to your tick list such that minor ticks can be added **between** two tick points.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis equal image,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
    ytick={0,1},
    minor y tick num={1},
    minor x tick num={1},
    xmin=-0.3, 
    xmax=4.2, 
    ymin=-0.3, 
    ymax=2.2,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel=$t$,
 ylabel=$s_6(t)$]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @wal-o-mat  My pleasure.